# URL Parameter Encoding and Rewriting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url-rewriting

As a learning experience for Ruby and Rails, I am creating a website for taking polls, stores the results, etc. As part of the polling process, a user has to go through a number of questions and provide answers to those questions. When they are done, they receive a list of recommendations based upon the answers they provided (of type Answer).

I have two parts to my question. One, I *think* I am heading down the right path. The other, I'm not even sure where to begin, and don't know if it is a good idea.

Here is my Answer model:

```
class Answer
  attr_accessor :question_number, :description, :answer
end
```

**Question 1**

I am looking for a way that, when the user submits all the answers (I'm storing their responses in session storage), it goes to my search function - but it is encoded nicely.

Instead of:

```
http://localhost:3000/results/search?[biglongstringofdifferentanswers]
```

I would like something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/results/search/1-answer_2-answer_3-answer
```

After doing some searching, it seems that what I want to accomplish has to be done with [the #parameterize method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001055), but I'm not sure I understand how to do that exactly.

**Question 2**

The second part to my question is - can I encode my answers so that they aren't directly human readable. I want to do this to prevent people from browsing to each other's answers. For example, the first answer is always the person's unique ID and I don't want to someone to be able to just browse to any old set of results by switching around parameters.

So, I am hoping to get something along the lines of:

```
http://localhost:3000/results/search/798dh832rhhbe89rbfb289f9234972bdbdbbws3
```

For this second question, I'm not even sure if this is a good idea, so I'm open to suggestions for this one.

Appreciate any help and guidance on these questions as I continue to explore/learn Ruby and RoR.

Comment: 1: what is the point of encoding your parameters? Rails allows you to catch it really easily on the server side like 'question = params[:question]. 2: why do you submit data through Get method? Should not you use Post method for this ?

Comment: @oldergod - 1. The functionality I am looking for is, I want a URL that the user can easily return to, and I want the values unique so different people can't browse to each other's results by just playing around with the JSON. 2. With respect to the POST vs. GET - that's where I am a bit confused and kind of why I'm asking the question in the first place. I could be doing this wrong (very, very possible), but hopefully this clarified a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, *there is not any login system* and you want submitted answers *that you store in your DB* to be accessable via url for the user. You said you don't want users to navigate to other users' answers but the user getting the url *can still share it*.

What I would do is to submit answers via POST method, so you don't have to worry about encoding your params etc. It gets then real easy with Rails.

You can add a public_id column to your answer object that would be a generated big int. After the post methoded submit, once you save the answer in your DB, you could return a redirect to the answer public id url.

something like

```
def create
  answer = Answer.new(params[:answer])
  if answer.save
    answer.generate_public_id # <= would be nice to add if in the answer model 'after_create' filter probably
    return redirect_to public_id_answer_path
  end
  render :partial => 'error'
end
```

What do you think ?